# Do I have to import images in my index.js file before I use them in webpack 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, webpack-5

I am currently following a tutorial on how to set up webpack 5 configuartion. However, i am not sure if I am handling the images correctly. The image only renders if i import them into my index.js file, it won't render if i don't. Is this how it is meant to work or  am I missing something. This is the only way it works in my template.html file `" <img src="f1.jpeg" />"` after importing it in my index.js file.

```
//index.js file



import f1 from './assets/f1.jpeg'
```

Here is my webpack config file.

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    bundle: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name][contenthash].js',
    clean: true,
    assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Webpack App',
      filename: 'index.html',
       template: 'src/template.html',
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
  ],
}
```

Here is an image of my folder structure
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dependency Graph](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/dependency-graph/) doc:

> Any time one file depends on another, webpack treats this as a dependency. This allows webpack to take non-code assets, such as images or web fonts, and also provide them as dependencies for your application.

> When webpack processes your application, it starts from a list of modules defined on the command line or in its configuration file. Starting from these entry points, webpack recursively builds a dependency graph that includes every module your application needs, then bundles all of those modules into a small number of bundles - often, only one - to be loaded by the browser.

If a module(code file, image, CSS, font etc..) is not included in the dependency graph, webpack will not bundle it, the module will not exist in the output directory.

- Use the image in the JS file.

> Now, when you `import MyImage from './my-image.png'`, that image will be processed and added to your output directory and the MyImage variable will contain the final url of that image after processing.

- Use the image in html template. `html-webpack-plugin` use the `lodash` [template engine](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/v5.5.3/lib/loader.js#L32), so you can use `require()` to load the image module.

E.g.

Project structure:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── cat.jpg
│   ├── index.html
│   └── mainfcac365f0ac79e03de87.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── images
│   │       └── cat.jpg
│   ├── index.html
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name][contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
    assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Webpack App',
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html',
    })
  ],
};
```

`src/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src='<%= require("./assets/images/cat.jpg") %>' />
</body>

</html>
```

Output

`dist/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
<script defer src="mainfcac365f0ac79e03de87.js"></script></head>

<body>
  <img src='cat.jpg' />
</body>

</html>
```

package versions:

```json
"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
"webpack": "^5.80.0",
"webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
```